# Comparing a value in a dictionary with an input number

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that is as follows.

`stock = {"samosa":5, "Kebab":5, "Shawarma":7}`

I also have input texts for entering values as follows

`food = input{"What was the food delivered: "}`
and for quantity as

`qty = input{" Enter the quantity of the order: "}`

So my comparison is checking and comparing quantity against the value of stock in the dictionary.
If someone orders for more, they get a message they have ordered more.
I have tried to implement that in this way.

```
if food in stock:
    stock[food] -= int(qty)
     print(stock)
elif int(qty) > stock[food]:
    print("There is no enough stock")
```

However it is not working as expected.

Comment: `elif` only happens if the first `if` is false. So you are saying: if food is not in stock, check if the quantity is greater that the stock (of the  thing you just determined is not in stock).

Comment: Wait.... Why a ```{}```instead of ```()```? ```input``` is a function. Doing ```input{...}``` will raise an error

Comment: @Sujay , that was an error in typing. Otherwise, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the food is in stock, check first if you can subtract the quantity:

```
if food in stock:
   if int(qty) > stock[food]:
      print("There is no enough stock")
   else:
      stock[food] -= int(qty)
      print(stock)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firs things first:

`input` is a **function**. You have to use `()` to call the function. If you do `input{...}`, an error will be raised.

```
food = input("What was the food delivered: ") 
qty = input(" Enter the quantity of the order: ")
```

Then, as @Mark Stated in the comments, you are checking if `food` is in `stock`. And, `elif` statement is executed **only** if `if` evaluates to `False`. So, `if food in stock` evaluates to `False`, the key doesn't exist in the dictionary. And then you fetch the `key:value` pair in `elif`: `elif int(qty) > stock[food]:`, thus raising a `KeyError`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
if food in stock:
    
    if int(qty) < stock[food]:
        stock[food] -= int(qty)
        print(stock)
    else:
        print("There is no enough stock")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your order of checking is wrong. After checking if the food is in stock you should check for quantity.

```
if food in stock:
    if int(qty) > stock[food]:
        print("There is no enough stock")
    else:
        stock[food] -= int(qty)
        print(stock)
```